# Java: String.getBytes(Charset) Vs. Charset.encode(String) for use with OutputStream

Tags: java, string, encoding, character-encoding, bytebuffer

I am in the situation that my algorithm has the 2 inputs of:

- 1 utf8 String object that will be encoded
- 1 Charset object which indicates what I need to encode the string into

In the end, the returned result will be put into an OutputStream, an action which may happen multiple times, but at least once. There is no multithreading happening in this scenario.

I have found two solutions:

1. Calling getBytes(Charset) on the given String and supply the given Charset. This will return a byte[]
2. Calling encode(String) on the given Charset and supply the given String. This will return a ByteBuffer.

Delving into the code behind these methods shows a complex design for each underlying algorithm. I can't say I understand how to make a choice between these two options.

1. Is there a significant performance difference for calling either method?
2. Is there a significant performance difference for putting the result into the OutputStream?
3. Is there a significant difference in footprint?

Which solution would generally be a better choice?

Comment: Most likely not, most likely not, most likely not, and use whichever you feel comfortable with. Micro-optimization like this is a waste of time.

Comment: @Kayaman I like the word `micro optimization`

Comment: @nafas A lot of people like the idea of it.

Comment: @Kayaman I could understand if you are developing an application that requires optimization on micro seconds levels. but for those that use java for such programs, I just say "good luck" :)

Comment: @nafas It all depends on the skills. For example Mr. Lawrey below has created several performance critical libraries with Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases, a `byte[]` is built dynamically to encode the string.  A more efficient approach is to have it written directly to the OutputStream. e.g.

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// look Mum, no byte[] needed
osw.write(text);
```

An alternetive would to use DataOutputStream.writeUTF if you need a binary format.

Comment: Except, `DataOutputStream.writeUTF` writes busted output ("modified UTF") if you use non-BMP characters.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young DataOutputStream.writeUTF is only really useful if you use DataInputStream.readUTF esp as it add two bytes as a length to the start. It doesn't corrupt characters for example.